# User "system:anonymous" cannot get path "/"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeadm

I just setup a kubenetes cluster base on this link https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#multi-platform
I check with kubectl get nodes, then the master node is Ready, but when I access to the link https://k8s-master-ip:6443/
it show the error: User "system:anonymous" cannot get path "/".
What is the trick I am missing ?

Comment: What are you expecting to see in that URL?

Comment: I think this url is kubenetes dashboard. Actually I'm configuring kubenetes plugin in Jenkins and I failed in Test Connection step. Please see my picture
http://imgur.com/a/cMNLo

Comment: That's not how you normally access the dashboard. Run `kubectl proxy` and then go to http://localhost:8001/ui. Make sure it's installed first with `kubectl create -f https://git.io/kube-dashboard`

Comment: @TienDungTran Have you managed to authenticate with Kubernetes in Jenkins in the meantime?

Answer (score 31):

Hope you see something like this:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    
  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

This is good as not everyone should be able to access the cluster, if you want to see the services run `"kubectl proxy"`, this should enable access to the services from the outside world.

```
C:\dev1> kubectl proxy
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
```

And when you hit `127.0.0.1:8001` you should see the list of services.

Answer (score 11):

The latest kubernetes deployment tools enable RBAC on the cluster. Jenkins is relegated to the catch-all user `system:anonymous` when it accesses `https://192.168.70.94:6443/api/v1/...`. This user has almost no privileges on kube-apiserver.

The bottom-line is, Jenkins needs to authenticate with kube-apiserver - either with a bearer token or a client cert that's signed by the k8s cluster's CA key.

**Method 1.** This is preferred if Jenkins is hosted in the k8s cluster:

1. Create a ServiceAccount in k8s for the plugin
2. Create an RBAC profile (ie. Role/RoleBinding or ClusterRole/ClusterRoleBinding) that's tied to the ServiceAccount
3. Config the plugin to use the ServiceAccount's token when accessing the URL `https://192.168.70.94:6443/api/v1/...`

**Method 2.** If Jenkins is hosted outside the k8s cluster, the steps above can still be used. The alternative is to:

1. Create a client cert that's tied to the k8s cluster's CA. You have to find where the CA key is kept and use it to generate a client cert.
2. Create an RBAC profile (ie. Role/RoleBinding or ClusterRole/ClusterRoleBinding) that's tied to the client cert
3. Config the plugin to use the client cert when accessing the URL `https://192.168.70.94:6443/api/v1/...`

Both methods work in any situation. I believe Method 1 will be simpler for you because you don't have to mess around with the CA key.

Answer (score -1):

By default, your clusterrolebinding has system:anonymous set which blocks the cluster access.

Execute the following command, it will set a clusterrole as cluster-admin which will give you the required access.

> kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-system-anonymous --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=system:anonymous

Comment: It's not safe to give anonymous (unauthenticated) users cluster admin permissions.