# Kubernetes authentication with certificate

Tags: authentication, ssl, jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-security

I am trying to authenticate with a locally hosted Kubernetes cluster (v1.6.4) using a certificate.
This takes part in the context of using the [Kubernetes plugin for Jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin).

I am following the guidelines for Minikube in the [Kubernetes-plugin README](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin) file which I adapted to my scenario:

1. Convert the client certificate to PKCS:

   ```
   $ sudo openssl pkcs12 -export -out kubernetes.pfx -inkey /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.key -in /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.crt -certfile /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt -passout pass:jenkins
   ```
2. In Jenkins, create credentials using a certificate

   1. `Kind`: `Certificate`
   2. `Certificate`: `Upload PKCS#12 certificate` and upload file `kubernetes.pfx`
   3. `Password`: `jenkins` (as specified during certificate creation)
3. `Manage Jenkins` -> `Add new cloud` -> `Kubernetes`

   1. `Kubernetes URL`: `https://10.179.1.121:6443` (as output by `kubectl config view`)
   2. `Kubernetes server certificate key`: paste the contents of `/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt`.
   3. `Disable https certificate check`: checked because the test setup does not have a signed certificate
   4. `Kubernetes Namespace`: tried both `default` and `kubernetes-plugin`
   5. `Credentials`: `CN=kube-apiserver` (i.e. the credentials created above)

Now when I click on `Test Connection`, this is the error message shown in the Jenkins Web UI:

> Error connecting to https://10.179.1.121:6443: Failure executing: GET at: https://10.179.1.121:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-plugin/pods. Message: Unauthorized.

The Jenkins logs show this message:

> Sep 05, 2017 10:22:03 AM io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config tryServiceAccount
>
> WARNING: Error reading service account token from: [/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token]. Ignoring.

The documentation is, unfortunately, mostly limited to Kubernetes running on Minikube and to Google Cloud Engine, but I do not see a conceptual difference between the former and a locally hosted Kubernetes cluster.

The following Curl call for testing results in a very different error message:

```
$ curl --insecure --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --cert kubernetex.pfx:secret https://10.179.1.121:6443
User "system:anonymous" cannot get  at the cluster scope.
```

More verbose:

```
$ curl -v --insecure --cacert /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt --cert kubernetex.pfx:secret https://10.179.1.121:6443
* About to connect() to 10.179.1.121 port 6443 (#0)
*   Trying 10.179.1.121...
* Connected to 10.179.1.121 (10.179.1.121) port 6443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* NSS: client certificate not found: kubernetex.pfx
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=kube-apiserver
*   start date: Jun 13 11:33:55 2017 GMT
*   expire date: Jun 13 11:33:55 2018 GMT
*   common name: kube-apiserver
*   issuer: CN=kubernetes
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 10.179.1.121:6443
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Content-Type: text/plain
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Date: Tue, 05 Sep 2017 10:34:23 GMT
< Content-Length: 57
< 
* Connection #0 to host 10.179.1.121 left intact
```

I have also set up a ServiceAccount:

```
$ kubectl describe serviceaccount --namespace=kubernetes-plugin 
Name:       default
Namespace:  kubernetes-plugin
Labels:     <none>
Annotations:    <none>

Image pull secrets: <none>

Mountable secrets:  default-token-6qwj1

Tokens:             default-token-6qwj1



Name:       jenkins
Namespace:  kubernetes-plugin
Labels:     <none>
Annotations:    <none>

Image pull secrets: <none>

Mountable secrets:  jenkins-token-1d623

Tokens:             jenkins-token-1d623
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45094665/user-systemanonymous-cannot-get-path/45097914#45097914) deals with a related problem, recommending to use either a ServiceAccount or a certificate, but the answer to the latter aproach lacks the details about how to tie an RBAC profile to that certificate. The [Kubernetes documentation about authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/) does not seem to cover this use case.

Answer (score 0):

The *WARNING: Error reading service account token* indicates that the key used to encrypt ServiceAccount tokens is different between kube-apiserver (--service-account-key-file) and kube-controller-manager (--service-account-private-key-file). If your kube-apiserver command-line doesn't specify --service-account-key-file then the value of --tls-private-key-file is used and I suspect that this is the issue.

I'd suggest always explicitly setting kube-apiserver --service-account-key-file to match the kube-controller-manager --service-account-private-key-file value.

Comment: I created the cluster using kubeadm, so no manual fiddling with these parameters. Any recommendations to fix this without restarting the kube-apiserver?