# Can not deploy application in multiple kubernetes clusters in local machine

Tags: docker, kubernetes, argocd, atlas

I wanted to deploy the application through argocd in kubernetes cluster. I have run the deployment of application within same cluster of argocd.
I want to run the argo cd in saperate cluster and want to migrate the database inside another cluster. For the same I have set two clusters in my local machine, one is inside docker-desktop enabled kubernetes, and one is inside minikube.

I want to run my argocd inside docker-desktop cluster and want to deploy the app inside minikube.
I have tried several times in different ways and everytime got different error. Listing below:

1. I have run the argocd in docker-desktop and want to deploy the app in minikube.

   - In this case I have to add the minikube as a cluster inside the argocd which is running in docker-desktop cluster. When I do the same by the command `argocd cluster add minikube` It was giving **connection refused** error. The error is related to [this](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/4204). and was not able to see the services inside the browser by hitting the endpoint of minikube service at binded port and got the **403-forbidden** error.
   - I found one solution from the stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71870953) And tried running the command: `kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-system-anonymous --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=system:anonymous`.
     Now I am able to add the cluster but still I can not deploy the app inside another cluster e.g. minikube. and getting the same error as **connection refused** **but this time now it is inside the argocd deployment logs**.
   - Now after this, When I try to deploy the application inside the same cluster I got the error as
     `Failed to load target state: failed to generate manifest for source 1 of 1: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing: dial tcp: lookup argocd-repo-server on 10.96.0.10:53: read udp 10.1.0.157:52399->10.96.0.10:53: read: connection refused"`.
2. Secondly, I tried with moving the argocd inside the minikube and deploy the apps inside docker-desktop. This time I was able to add the cluster in argo cd with the command `argocd cluster add docker-desktop` successfully without any error. But when i deploy the app to configure the deployment in the docker desktop. it is giving error as **resource not found**.
   In this case It is not able to find any of the resources like configmaps, deployments. And giving error as `cannot find the defined resource: apiVersion: db.atlasgo.io/v1alpha1,kind:AtlasMigration and apiVersion: v1,kind: ConfigMap`. p.s. I have already installed atlas in minikube.

Git repo url: [git-repository](https://github.com/Test-org-for-gia-project/migration-testing.git).

If anyone has tried to deploy the application in another cluster than argocd relies. It will be Great help.

Comment: are you able to access one cluster from a pod within the other by just using `kubectl`?

Comment: No. I was just wanted to add one local cluster inside another local cluster like docker-desktop and minikube. So anyways I wasn't able to do so by just using `kubectl`. I think the problem was, from inside docker-desktop(works as a saperate environment) we can not reach to the minikube which is reachable from local machine.